# How to navigate through java menu items with arrow keys (up/down)?

Tags: java, swing, navigation, key, jmenu

I have a menu with menu items. I programmatically select the menu and expand it:

```
// Create new menu with menu items
JMenu jMenuFile = new JMenu("File");
JMenuItem jMenuItemNew = new JMenuItem("New");
jMenuFile.add(jMenuItemNew );
JMenuItem jMenuItemOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
menuFile.add(jMenuItemOpen);

// Select menu and expand it
jMenuFile.setSelected(true);                
jMenuFile.setPopupMenuVisible(true);
```

This code works fine, but I cannot navigate manually through the menu items with the arrow keys (up/down). How can this be achieved?

Note 1: If I set a mnemonic key 
(jMenuFile.setMnemonic ('D')),  I get the focus and I can use the arrow keys. However, I don't want to use the mnemonic keys.

Note 2: jMenuFile.requestFocus() doesn't work either.

Comment: you forgot to call show/setVisible for container (if (parent instanceof JPopupMenu) {), before anything to test for if isShowing, thats it, thare are a two listeners, you can to use that as notifier for testing purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
jMenuDatei.doClick();
```

This simulates a click on the menu. Therefore, it is selected and I can navigate through the menu items using the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you first have to set a [mnemonic key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic-char-). With "Alt+mnemonic key" the related menu should get the focus. I guess then it should also be possible to use the arrow keys as well (not sure).

Comment: Once the menu is opened (in focus) you can use the arrows to navigate, that's true.